# Magento 2 How to unlock the consumer

Tags: magento2, message-queue, rabbit-mq, queue

We are using Magento 2.4.5-p5 EE and RabbitMQ message broker. The **exportProcessor** consumer is not consuming messages from the queue automatically (cron job **consumers_runner** is running every minute), other consumers are working fine. If we run command "php bin/magento queue:consumer:start exportProcessor" it consumes messages.
On debugging, we found that "exportProcessor" consumer is **locked** and hence it is not consuming messages. When we run command the logic in the code **unlocks** the consumer and it works as expected.
I checked the **queue_lock** table, it is empty.

Any suggestions on Where can we find the lock and delete it ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to unlock the consumer after restarting the MySQL service.